# url without www doesn't work but set up properly?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

typing `www.server.com.au` in a web browser works fine I want to be able to access the web by entering `server.com.au` too

- A name record exists only for www.server.com.au
- CNAME for both and A name for server.com.au don't exist

---

my `/etc/apache2/listen.conf` contains lines

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.com.au
    ServerAlias server.com.au 
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/www.server.com.au/www
</VirtualHost>
```

and list of virtual servers gives me

```
[root][saas1 /srv/www/htdocs/www.server.com.au/www] httpd2 -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server server.com.au (/etc/apache2/listen.conf:47)
     port 80 namevhost server.com.au (/etc/apache2/listen.conf:47)
```

but `http://server.com.au` is not accessible

I restart the server by `httpd2 -k restart`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want both "server.com.au" and "www.server.com.au" to work,, then both of those hosts need to have DNS records setup.

You can either:

- give both of them an A record, pointing at the same IP address
- give server.com.au an A record, pointing at the IP address of your server, and give www.server.com.au a CNAME, pointing at server.com.au.

I suspect the first approach is easier, because you already have an A record setup for www.server.com.au.

As I suggested in a comment, you really don't want to use a CNAME on the "server.com.au" record. This violates the spec, and while it may look like it works, can do unpredictable things. Far better to just stay away from putting a CNAME on "server.com.au" entirely.

Once you've got that working, you'll need to make sure apache knows about both names - which has already been covered by the discussion around ServerAlias and ServerName directives.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `ServerAlias www.server.com.au` instead of `ServerAlias server.com.au` was that a typo ?

If you do not want the www then just delete `ServerAlias server.com.au` all you gona need is the `ServerName`

Comment: @prix I tried both `ServerAlias www.server.com.au` and `ServerAlias server.com.au` and none worked. I want the site to be accessible using both www and without www

Comment: @Radek, do you have a DNS A or CNAME record for www.server.com.au?

Comment: @ErikA: I have no idea.How can I find out?Note that www.server.com.au works fine. It's server.com.au that is not accessible.

Comment: @Radek - oh, then do you have a valid DNS A or CNAME for server.com.au?

Comment: @ErikA:
A name record exists only for www.server.com.au
CNAME for both and A name for server.com.au don't exist

Comment: can I solve that without creating/updating these records?

Comment: @Radek - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make sure that you have valid DNS A record set for `server.com.au` and either an A or CNAME for `www.server.com.au`, depending on your needs. This is the only way that your customers' browsers will be able to know which server to contact to access your website.

Comment: You do NOT want a CNAME for server.com.au, this will stop a lot of things working. You cannot have a CNAME and other records (such as A, MX, and most importantly, NS records).

Comment: @Daniel Lawson: so, what's the solution? :-)

Comment: Clarified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
   ServerName www.server.com.au
   ServerAlias   server.com.au
   ServerAlias *.server.com.au
```

and you can also create a WildCard 'A' record
it will make anything.server.com.au work.